# Getting "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.awspring.cloud.jdbc.config.annotation.AmazonRdsInstanceConfiguration" when working with Amazon SES

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-ses

I am trying to get my spring application to run with Amazon SES but keep getting an exception during the build process saying "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.awspring.cloud.jdbc.config.annotation.AmazonRdsInstanceConfiguration" I was following an example online at https://stackabuse.com/guide-to-simple-email-service-aws-ses-with-spring-boot-and-spring-cloud/

Here is my Config file

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailService;
import com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder;
import io.awspring.cloud.ses.SimpleEmailServiceMailSender;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;

@Configuration
public class AmazonSESConfig {

    @Value("${amazon.aws.accessKey}")
    private String accessKey;
    @Value("${amazon.aws.secretKey}")
    private String secretKey;

    @Value("${amazon.aws.region}")
    private String region;

    @Bean
    public AmazonSimpleEmailService amazonSimpleEmailService() {
        BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
        return AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .withRegion(region)
                .build();

    }

    @Bean
    public MailSender mailSender(AmazonSimpleEmailService amazonSimpleEmailService) {
        return new SimpleEmailServiceMailSender(amazonSimpleEmailService);
    }
}
```

Here is my properties file

```
amazon.aws.accessKey=ACCESS_KEY
amazon.aws.secretKey=SECRET_KEY
amazon.aws.region=ca-central-1
```

Here is my service file

```
@Service
public class CorrespondenceService {

    @Autowired
    private MailSender mailSender;

    public void sendMail(){
    
        SimpleMailMessage simpleMailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
        simpleMailMessage.setFrom("testFromEmail@test.com");
        simpleMailMessage.setTo("testToEmail@test.com");
        simpleMailMessage.setSubject("Test");
        simpleMailMessage.setText("This email is a test");

        mailSender.send(simpleMailMessage);


    }

}
```

Finally here is the error from the console.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [io.awspring.cloud.jdbc.config.annotation.AmazonRdsInstanceConfiguration]
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:334) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adapt(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:446) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.getValue(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:369) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.asAnnotationAttributes(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:193) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:106) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.attributesFor(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:285) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.determineBeanNameFromAnnotation(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:103) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.java:82) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitionForImportedConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:169) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:150) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
        at *MY APPLICATION PATH*(MyApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.awspring.cloud.jdbc.config.annotation.AmazonRdsInstanceConfiguration
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:495) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:474) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:145) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:495) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:474) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.resolveClassName(ClassUtils.java:324) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Here is the main class

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class EmailApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmailApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add your main class for this project? It seems to be coming from some configuration in there somewhere.

Comment: @grekier I have added the main class, but I have not modified that file at all so not sure it will help

Comment: I see... that's definitively not the issue... Do you have any other classes annotated with `@Configuration` or `@Import` maybe? BTW, class name should start with an uppercase in Java

Comment: Oh  thats not the actual class name, I just put that there for confidentiality purposes.  and yes I do have another config file, but its for my dynamoDB configuration. and that works fine

Comment: So I'm not sure where it is coming from but, in any cases, the error is caused because something somewhere is annotated with something that needs AmazonRdsInstanceConfiguration and it isn't there. Obviously you could add `spring-cloud-aws-jdbc` as a dependency but, if it is not in use, it would be better to figure out why it's expected

Comment: Yea that was what I found when looking into it, but it seems that adding that dependency requires you to use things that I don't need, and thus throws even more errors at me

Answer (score 1):

*I don't have enough reputations to provide as a comment, so forced to give what worked for me as an answer.*

I got the same error while working on a project. I updated my application-local.yml like below which resolved it.

```
cloud:
  aws:
    rds:
      enabled: false
```

I feel this is just a fix to the problem but not actually figuring out the root cause behind the issue. I'll update when I get more info on the issue.